# Add to cart $_SESSION has been destroy after logged in

Tags: php, session

Why my `$_SESSION["products"]` has been destroy after logged in, How do I keep my `$_SESSION["products"]` after I logged in?

Add product to cart before logged in.

[image]

---

After logged in my cart is empty.

[image]

---

**CODE**

**login.php**

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'init.php';
require_once 'config.php'; 
//initalize user class
$user_obj = new Cl_User();
    if(!empty( $_POST )){
        try {
            $user_obj = new Cl_User();
            $data = $user_obj->login( $_POST );
            if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']){
                header('Location: home.php');
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']){
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Smart Login Page</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php require_once 'templates/ads.php';?>
        <div class="login-form">
            <?php require_once 'templates/message.php';?>
            <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
            <div class="form-header">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <form id="login-form" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus> 
                <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">

                <button class="btn btn-block bt-login" type="submit" id="submit_btn" data-loading-text="loging in....">Login</button>
                <br>
            </form>
            <div class="form-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        <a href="forget_password.php"> Forgot Password? </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        <a href="register.php"> Sign up </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

**login function in User.php**

```
public function login( array $data )
    {

        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
        if( !empty( $data ) ){

            // Trim all the incoming data:
            $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);

            // escape variables for security
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['password'] );


            if((!$email) || (!$password) ) {
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
            }
            $password = md5( $password );
            $query = "SELECT member_id, member_display_name, member_email, member_status, roles_id FROM fm_member where member_email = '$email' and member_pwd = '$password' ";
            //$query = "SELECT user_id, name, email, created, roles_id, id FROM users where email = '$email' and password = '$password'"
            $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            mysqli_close($this->_con);
            if( $count == 1){
                $_SESSION = $data;
                if($_SESSION['member_status'] == 'Activated') {
                        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                        return true;
                } else {
                    throw new Exception( 'Your account is Deactiavted! <br> Please contact to Adminnistrator for more information.' );
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
                }
            }else{
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FAIL );
            }
        } else{
            throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
        }

    }
```

**cart_process.php**

```
session_start(); //start session
include_once("config.inc.php"); //include config file
setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_US"); // US national format (see : http://php.net/money_format)
############# add products to session #########################
if(isset($_POST["product_code"]))
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $new_product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //create a new product array 
    }
    //we need to get product name and price from database.
    $statement = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT fm_product.p_name, fm_product.p_price, fm_product.p_member_id, fm_product.p_discount, fm_member.member_display_name, fm_member.member_payment, fm_product_image.img_1, shipping_cost.shipping_register,
    shipping_cost.shipping_normal, shipping_cost.shipping_ems FROM fm_product LEFT JOIN fm_member ON fm_member.member_id = fm_product.p_member_id LEFT JOIN fm_product_image ON fm_product_image.p_id_img = fm_product.p_id LEFT JOIN shipping_cost ON shipping_cost.shipping_vendor = fm_member.member_id WHERE p_id=?");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $new_product['product_code']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($product_name, $product_price, $p_member_id, $p_discount, $member_display_name, $member_payment, $img_1, $shipping_register, $shipping_normal,$shipping_ems);


    while($statement->fetch()){ 
        $new_product["p_name"] = $product_name; //fetch product name from database
        $new_product["p_price"] = $product_price;
        $new_product["p_member_id"] = $p_member_id;
        $new_product["p_discount"] = $p_discount;
        $new_product["member_display_name"] = $member_display_name;
        $new_product["member_payment"] = $member_payment;
        $new_product["img_1"] = $img_1;
        $new_product["shipping_register"] = $shipping_register;
        $new_product["shipping_normal"] = $shipping_normal;
        $new_product["shipping_ems"] = $shipping_ems;
        //fetch product price from database

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])){  //if session var already exist
            if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_code']])) //check item exist in products array
            {
                unset($_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_code']]); //unset old item
            }           
        }

        $_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_code']] = $new_product; //update products with new item array   
    }

    $total_items = count($_SESSION["products"]); //count total items
    die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items))); //output json 

}

################## list products in cart ###################
if(isset($_POST["load_cart"]) && $_POST["load_cart"]==1)
{

    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){ //if we have session variable
        $cart_box = '<ul class="cart-products-loaded">';
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){ //loop though items and prepare html content

            //set variables to use them in HTML content below
            $product_name = $product["p_name"]; 

            if(!empty($product["p_discount"]))
            {
                $product_price = $product["p_discount"];
            } else if(empty($product["p_discount"])) {
                $product_price = $product["p_price"];
            }

            $product_code = $product["product_code"];
            $p_member_id = $product["p_member_id"];
            $member_display_name = $product["member_display_name"];
            $member_payment = $product["member_payment"];
            $product["product_qty"] = 1;
            $product_qty = $product["product_qty"];


            $cart_box .=  "<li>$product_name &mdash; Price ".$product_price." x ".$product_qty." = ".sprintf($product_qty * $product_price)."<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"remove-item\" data-code=\"$product_code\">&times;</a></li>";
            $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);
        }
        $cart_box .= "</ul>";
        $cart_box .= '<div class="cart-products-total" style="border-top: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">'.$quantity.'Total : '.sprintf($total).'<a href="check_out.php" title="Review Cart and Check-Out" style="margin-left: 10px;"><u>Check Out</u></a></div>';
        die($cart_box); //exit and output content
    }else{
        die("Empty Cart!"); //we have empty cart
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

**home.php added**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('connect.php');

$ID = $_SESSION['member_id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
<?php require_once 'templates/header.php';?>
    <?php if($_SESSION['roles_id']=='1') { ?>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <br>
                <h1 class="text-center"> Admin Page </h1>
                <br>
            </div>
            <?php require_once 'templates/sidebar.php';?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <?php } else if($_SESSION['roles_id']=='2') { ?>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <br>
                <h1 class="text-center"> User Page </h1>
                <br>
            </div>
            <?php require_once 'templates/sidebar.php';?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Although you should considder using Prepared Statements instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, I don't see any reason why that code would destroy a session. Nevertheless the code redirects to `home.php` and the issue might be inside that one. Could you update your question with it?

Comment: @icecub `home.php` added

Comment: Also: Using md5 hashing for password encryption on an online store is a very bad idea. You're working with highly sensative private customer data like their payment details. If you at some point get hacked, and with md5 that WILL happen, no insurrence is going to cover for you as your script was insecure. But that's just a tip

Comment: @icecub Thank you for your tip.

Comment: Ok so the issue isn't there either. I think the problem has something to do with `$_SESSION = $data;` inside your login class. I never worked with it like that, but I suspect it's putting everything inside `$data` in the session array while destroying everything that was already there before.

Comment: @icecub Okay, I'll check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104693/discussion-between-vintage-beef-and-icecub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like $_SESSION = $data; may be your culprit, you're resetting the entire session variable with data.

**EDIT**

Where $_SESSION = $data is change it to this;

```
$data["products"] = $_SESSION["products"];
$_SESSION = $data;
```

Comment: @JoshS. What I don't get though, is why this works? Because putting `$_SESSION = $data;` after it, should still reset the entire array? I was working with him on something like `array_push($_SESSION, $data);`

Comment: Glad I could help but in case $_SESSION["products"] isn't set, change the line to this --  $data["products"] = $_SESSION["products"] ?: array();

Comment: Yes, it does. what you are doing is setting the products portion of the session into data, so when data resets session, it contains products still. data doesn't have products when you go to set it. that piece of code makes sure it does.

Comment: Ah ofc! Sry I misread your solution in the first place. Well done m8! +1 from me